# I'm looking for a quote similar to "do not judge me by my faults, rather judge me by my lack of awareness and desire to change them"

Tags: quotes

I've heard a quote similar to the following message and am having a hard time finding it.

> "*Do not judge me by my faults, rather judge me by my lack of awareness
>   and desire to change them?*"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a search for a quotation.

Comment: Can you recommend where else I could ask this question on stack exchange and I'll close it and reopen it?

Comment: I don't have a recommendation, but perhaps someone else will. In any case, wait to see if others agree that it should be closed here. Mine is only one opinion. Thx.

Comment: To what does "them" refer? Faults?  The question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Drew Sources of or similar sounding quotes are considered on-topic at ELU.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a search for a quotation.

Answer (score 2):

Attributed to William James, Napoleon, and others, and harshly worded but ultimately kind:

> Never ascribe to malice that which can be explained by incompetence.